# ssrs 2008 r2 sort on a group displayed in a tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In an existing SSRS 2008 r2 report, I am trying to determine how to change the sort order of a grouping called termName in a tablix. The school terms are sorted in descending order. The termName column is defined as varchar(10), not null .
 The values for termName are the following:
 T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11, and T12.

The problem is the term names end up not have T12 sorted first followed by T11 then followed  by T10 then followed  by T9.

The sort ends displaying the terms incorrectly in the following order:
 T9,T8,T7,T6,T5,T4,T3,T2,T1,T12,T11,and then T10.

Could I possibly use IIF expressions on the sort and/or on the location in the SSRS 2008 r2 report where the value is dispalyed? If so, can you show me what I can do?

Thus can you tell me what I can do sort on the tablix?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=iif(Fields!termName.Value=”T12”,”1″,  
 iif(Fields!termName.Value=”T11”,”2″,  
 iif(Fields!termName.Value=”T10”,”3″,  
 ””)))
```

etc, adding a line for all the terms
Just add to the group sort expression

Comment: @user1816979 Grateful if you mark as answered / upvote